# How to fix the position of a text to follow an object plotted in R

Tags: r, plot

I was wondering how I can fix a piece of `text()` to always appear above a bracket (or a `points()` etc.) in a dynamically changing plot? **In other words**, how should I determine the **"x"** and **"y"** for that piece of text to follow the bracket (or a `points()` etc.) around anywhere in the plot? (**see my R code below**)

Just as an example, suppose I have a bracket in the plot below whose position (xs and ys) is going to be always known regardless of how the plot will change. Here, **how can I fix the position of the `text()` above this bracket (as currently seen in the plot) no matter where the bracket goes?**

**P.S.** At first, I thought I can take the "y" of the bracket, and then make "y" of the `text()` to be: (**"y" of bracket + .1* "y" of bracket**). But given that the plot can dynamically change (i.e., the plot is connected to a function), **+ .1* "y" of bracket** in any plot gives a different position for the text that doesn't guarantee the distance between he text and the bracket be always maintained.

[image]

**Here is a piece of R code:**

```
if(!require(library(pBrackets))){install.packages('pBrackets') }

library(pBrackets)

plot(1:10, ty = 'n')

brack <- brackets(x1 = 4, y1 = 6, x2 = 8, y2 = 6, h = 1, ticks = .5, curvature = .5, 
              type=1, col = "blue", 
              lwd = 2, xpd = T)

text(x = 6, y = 7.2, "Equivalent to ZERO", font = 2) ## How to determine "x" and "y"
                                                      # such that the "text" always
                                                      # appears above the bracket 
                                                      # even if the plot changes. This helps making functions.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
plot(1:10, ty = 'n')
x1 = 4
y1 = 6
x2 = 8
y2 = 6
h = 1 #Or some variation of h = sqrt( (x2-x1)^2 + (y2-y1)^2 )/4
brack <- brackets(x1 = x1, y1 = y1, x2 = x2, y2 = y2, h = h, ticks = .5, curvature = .5, 
                      type=1, col = "blue", 
                      lwd = 2, xpd = T)

text(x = (x1+x2)/2, y = (y1+h), "Equivalent to ZERO", font = 2, pos = 3)
#pos = 3 means the text will be on top of x and y
```

Comment: Actually one issue is with determining the height  (`h`) of the bracket given that the plot can change in any way?